# For: y1'= ay1 + ay2 and y2'= ay1 - y2 find the values of a, such that the critical point at y=0 is stable and attractive?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, the question seems simple but I get stuck on the working. Any help would be great:

I know that the critical point would be stable when the sum of the eigen values of the system are equal to zero and the product of them is greater than zero.

So, I thought it would be a simple case of calculating the eigen values and then solving for a.

I set up the matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}y1'\\y2'\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}a&a\\a&-1\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}y1\\y2\end{bmatrix}

I then calculated the eigen values (or tried to): 
\begin{bmatrix}a-λ&a\\a&-1-λ\end{bmatrix} =0

when solving this I get:

λ^2 +(-a+1)λ - a^2 -a =0

After that, I tried to solve for lambda but the answer is a mess and doesn't help.

I'm not really sure where to proceed from here. Help solving would be much appreciated.

Comment: "I know that the critical point would be stable when the sum of the eigen values of the system are equal to zero and the product of them is greater than zero." Sure about that?

Comment: Thanks for that! I got that far too actually, but then tried to go further and solve for 'a' itself.

Comment: According to my textbook, the conditions for a critical point which is stable and attractive are eigen values which sum to 0 and when multiplied, are greater than zero... although I understand that seems impossible!

Comment: As you'd expect, there's a center point at (0,0) when you plot this function. It doesn't help too much with finding the criterion for a, but I'll keep working on it! I perhaps am a bit confused about the textbook's definition for a stable and attractive critical point!

Comment: For example, when you evaluate for a=1 you get λ1,2 = 1.41 and -1.41. That satisfies the criteria for p being equal to zero. But their product is negative. Then, increasing a to be a large positive or negative doesn't help with satisfying that the product of p and q has to be greater than zero as the two eigenvalues always have opposite signs.

Comment: I actually didn't mean as on page 45. My reference had 'q >0' but your link says has the condition as 'q=0' - for the critical point to be stable and attractive. There must have been a misprint in my book. Given the conditions in your link it's simple to see that if a were 0 or -1, then the critical point would be stable and attractive. Many thanks for the time you put into helping with the question and providing the good resource. Will be referencing it in future.